# Pointing to a private method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, private

I have a public method within a class that needs to point to a private method, how would I do this?

```
public class test1
{
    private  String lastName;
    private  String firstName;
    public   String name; 

    public void setup()
     {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the last name followed by the first name of" +
                " a student: ");
        lastName = in.next();
        firstName = in.next();                      
    }
    private void setName() {
        name = firstName + " " + lastName;
        name = name.replaceAll(",([^,]*)$", "$1");
    }
```

How would I point to the setName() method from the setup() method? And yes, I do need the setName() method even though I could just put all of that information into the setup() method.

Comment: You may be over-thinking all of this. Just simply  **call** the `setName(...)` method from within the `setup()` method, simple as that. You will use it to pass in the appropriate information after you get it of course.

Comment: As @HovercraftFullOfEels told you, you just need to add `setName()` at the end of `setup`.

Comment: A method in a class can call any other method in that class.  Having one `private` makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that your setName method is a **setter** method or "**mutator** method, and as such it should set the state of a property or field of your class. For it to work,  you need to give it a parameter to allow anyone calling it to pass information in to the method, and yours does not do this.

Edit: I take that back. Your problem is your method is mis-named as it's not really a setter method at all. Change it to something else, say `manipulateName()`, and then call it **after** calling your public setter methods.

For example:

```
public Foo {
  private String bar;

  public void setup() {
      //.... use Scanner to get bar String....
      String innerBar = scanner.nextLine();

      setBar(innerBar);

      // here's the private method to manipulate stuff
      changeBar();
  }

  public void setBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public String getBar() {
    return bar;
  }

  private void changeBar() {
     // do something with bar here
     bar = bar.replaceAll(",([^,]*)$", "$1");
  }
```

Comment: @DavidConrad: I've edited my answer before seeing your comment, perhaps I have addressed this. His private method isn't a setter at all.

Comment: This is not a Java Bean, `setName` just initializes name field, it is not a setter.